# How to implement a friends relation in Sails.js..?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I am very new to sails.js and I want to make an app whihc has a friends relation.. i.e a User can have many friends..

In general we would make a `Friend` relation in which `user1` and `user2` would be two foreign keys to the `User` relation. But I am having trouble in implementing this in sails.js. How can I do that..??

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation found [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models), it reads

> Associations are not yet available for Sails.JS, however are on the immediate todo list. Please check out issue #124 for more information regarding the proposed changes for associations.

That said, what I ended up doing is querying the DB multiple times to try and fake it.

```
Friends.find({id: <some_id_here>}).done(function(friend){
   return Users.findAll({where: {friendId: friend.id}})  
   //Since this returns a promise, we'll deal with it in the next one. 
}).done(function(users){
   //do stuff. 
})
```

This missing feature alone is part of the reason that I ended up dropping Sails for just writing a custom job in Express using Sequelize.

Comment: Associations are available in sails 0.10 (currently in beta). http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations

Answer (score 1):

At Sails@beta (0.10.0-rc9)

Maybe something like this could work:

**Models/User.js**

```
module.exports = {
    friends: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'friends'
    }
}
```